# How likely are we to see a Vala web framework?

Tags: web-frameworks, vala

Web frameworks are everywhere, and I can't think of a programming language that hasn't a web framework implementation (at least those that I know of). Vala seems the programming language Linux developers were waiting for since ages, it borrows a lot from C# which is very good IMHO.

Yes, Vala was implemented to develop good Gnome applications, but still; we've seen crazy implementations like node.js. How likely are we to see a Vala based web framework? Is it feasible? Is it a good idea?

Answer (score 7):

There is a web framework called [Valum](https://github.com/antono/valum) in development. It's just been started, so it still very basic.

As an aside, I've not seen a web framework in plain C, otherwise, that could be bound to Vala.

Comment: One interesting perspective for Valum is possibility to use this framework from other languages via GObject Introspection. So Valum is not only for vala but for everyone :)

Comment: Isn't there an inherent detriment to using compiled languages for web development (i.e., languages without a VM or runtime)? I'm under the impression that such languages require CGI which is inherently bad for the web (lots of OS overhead in dispatching a new task for each page request, perhaps?) Is this true and if so would Valum or any other Vala web framework share this woe?

Comment: No. A compiled language can have a persistent server with an event dispatch model too. The FastCGI interface can be consumed just as efficiently with C. In fact, think of how efficient Apache is, written in C, using an internal dispatch to some languages via the `mod_` system.

Comment: Right, but Apache stays up all the time. The OS doesn't kick off a new process every time the user makes an HTTP request. With PHP or Python, you have a persistent interpreter managing the PHP programs running therein (not the OS), and you aren't required to implement your own server. I'm curious if you can write your own compiled program without having to write your own persistent server, but without having the expense of traditional CGI. Also, I vaguely recall reading in the Python docs that FastCGI still isn't on par with Python's standard web solution, but I may be mistaken.

Comment: You can simply keep your server persistently up. Also, the OS does not start the process, that is a design decision of the web server; CGI kicks of new processes, FastCGI or other proxying connects to a running external server, Apache's `mod_` infrastructure loads the sever into Apache's own memory space. Alternatively, your external process can simply be a webserver (e.g., Tomcat). Also, this is now irrelevant to the OP.

Comment: Gotcha, well thank you for the information. I won't further derail the topic.